# Handling null records while converting TXT file (C# or any other language)

Tags: c#

I've been trying to solve this for a long long time but i could not solved it.

I need to convert a txt file, i want to **replace the spaces** by commas but there are some scenarios where null records exist.

My TXT file looks like this:

```
POL-45345334234       -963747       -963747 $   KAN  98   HU 554534     2179007             2021 20210127 20210127       -963747              
POL-99345552342        628308        423818 $   KAN  98   JU 999898     1402048             2021 20190104 20190208        423818   30        0
```

If you take a look, the TXT file has 15 columns but some records do not fill all the columns, just a few of them.

I would like to obtain something like this:

```
POL-45345334234,-963747,-963747,$,KAN,98,HU,554534,2179007,2021,20210127,20210127,-963747,,              
POL-99345552342,628308,423818,$,KAN,98,JU,999898,1402048,2021,20190104,20190208,423818,30,0
```

Look closer to this:

```
,,
```

A guy suggested me to use something like this:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions;

       using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\output.csv"))
        {
            using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    string line = String.Empty;
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        string newline = Regex.Replace(line, @"\s+", ",");
                        sw.WriteLine(newline);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is that by doing that i am not considering null records and it is not really useful.

How can i manage that situation? have any idea?

Comment: Have you tried csvhelper?

Comment: Is it right aligned? If so, you need to know where the column ends, and if you haven't seen a value up to that point, there is no value for that column. On the other hand, if it were left aligned, you would need to know where the column begins, and if you don't see a value at that point, there is no value for that column. Is there a row with titles for the columns? You could use it to get the positioning of the columns.

Comment: @Theraot Hey pal, thanks for replying. No, i do not have titles for the columns :/. I do not fully understand what do you mean by right or left aligned.

Comment: @mjwills yeah, it was not very usefull at all

Comment: See in your example `-963747` and `628308` match on the right. This makes me thing that the numbers are right aligned. And thus the way to check if there is a value on that column in to read up to the character where the column ends. Without column titles, you might have to discover the position along the way, which makes this way more complicated. Imagine you are reading the first row, and there is a gap, is it because the column is very wide, or is it because there is a column but you are yet to find a row with a value there? Knowing what columns can be null and which are numeric would help.

Comment: Perhaps if the columns are always of the same width, and you have enough of these files to be confident about that, then you can hard code their positions.

Comment: @Theraot i'm trying something up. Gonna keep you updated!

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that the lines are fixed width and the start positions of the columns all line up. So if you take substrings for each line that correspond to each column you can trim the spaces away from each of the columns individually.

You can replace the Regex line with

```
string newline = ParseLine(line);
```

and introduce a parse function like this

```cs
string ParseLine(string line)
{
    string separator = ",";
    int[] starts = new int[] { 0, 22, 36, 43, 47, 53, 57, 60, 71, 91, 96, 105, 121, 130, 140, 142 };
    List<string> row = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < starts.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        row.Add(line.Substring(starts[i], starts[i + 1] - starts[i]).Trim());
    }
    return String.Join(separator, row);
}
```

The function can be more elaborate and automatically adjust to different spacings but hopefully its a start.

Comment: Something along these lines is what I was suggesting in the comments. +1. Edit: to be clear `starts` here is meant to be the positions of the columns.

Comment: Hey pal, thanks for commenting!
I'm looking your parse function

Comment: @Theraot thanks for clarifying that. Yes, it is meant to be the start positions of the columns except the last entry. That is the length of a line to avoid a separate end-case after the for loop.

Comment: @programming_amazing you can try these values: `0, 15, 29, 43, 45, 51, 55, 60, 67, 79, 96, 105, 114, 128, 133, 142`. Those are the *ends*, which is what you would need if the values grow to the left, that is that they are right aligned. The result is the same of the example rows. Edit: perhaps some grow to the left, some to the right? I don't know. I see a gap before what conspicuously looks like a year. I don't think I'll be around to see this software runs for eons.

Comment: @Theraot i got a doubt: what would it change it i used *0, 19, 34, 45, 49, 52, 58, 65, 69, 85, 99, 110, 116, 132, 140, 145*

Comment: @programming_amazing considering that humans are falible and that you have more test data than us… Go with what works.  With that said, `65`, `99` and `110` do not seem right. Some others seem to be off by one, but that could be on my end. I had to add some spaces at the end for `145` to work, perhaps lost in the copy to this site… I got this using the numbers you post: `"POL-99345552342,628308,423818 $,K,AN,98,JU 9998,98,1402048,2021 20,190104 2019,0208,423818   3,0,0"`. As I said, does not seem right.

Comment: @programming_amazing Inserting a space at the start I got this: `"POL-99345552342,628308,423818,$,KAN,98,JU 999,898,1402048,2021 2,0190104 201,90208,423818,30,0"`

Comment: @Theraot Yeah, my bad. I was using a different data. :D

Answer (score 1):

I assume the missing columns are always to the right.

You can then use this code which adds a line to your code:

```
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string newline = Regex.Replace(line.Trim(), @"\s+", ",");
    newline += new string(',', 14 - Regex.Matches(newline, ",").Count);
    sw.WriteLine(newline);
}
```

What it does is to count the `number of commas` in the line. It then subtracts it from 14.

Finally it adds that may commas to the line.

That should always give 14 commas.

Note, I have added `Trim()` to the line, makes it more safe.

Comment: Hey pal, thanks for replying!
I'm checking it out